# How do I extract a list a list of name from a json file in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, twitter

I'm trying to extract list of names from json file called WW_trend, which contains a dict called trends, with a list of all the trending topics from X period of time

```
world_trends = set([... for trend in ...])
```

this code chunk is what im supposed to use (start from basically i dont know what im supposed to add)

```
world_trends = set([name for trend in WW_trends:
                       name = trend['name']])
```

I tried this but I get back invalid syntax.

Comment: You're making a set out of a *list comprehension*, I suggest some research on what syntax is valid for that.

Comment: Great question on list comprehension. This one was a bit advance version of list comprehension.

Comment: Do you mind post the original json data?

Comment: By the way, the list comprehension syntax is wrong. I would suggest fixing the problem with the normal for loop, if you can do that and post it, it would be much easier for guys to help you change it to list comprehension, although that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would be:

```
world_trends = set()
for trend in WW_trends:
    try:
        world_trends.add(trend['name'])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Ok. There might be some thing missing in the json. I have updated the code according to the problem you said is coming.